# Is the word 'grace' mentioned in the koran? If so what is the meaning of it?

Tags: quran

When I look on wikipedia at 'grace' then they refer to a Christian interpretation. Although it is mentioned also in the Old Testament the sit is not very much speaking of it. But there is never spoken about 'grace' in Islam, so is it used and what does it mean?

Comment: There are a lot of definitions associated with this word. What do you exactly mean by "grace": "do honor or credit to (someone or something) by one's presence" or something else?

Comment: There are mentions of "grace" in different translations of the Quran to English.

Have a look: http://quran.com/search?q=grace

Comment: Grace means : grace has been defined, not as a created substance of any kind, but as "the love and mercy given to us by God because God desires us to have it, not because of anything we have done to earn it"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the concept of grace exist in Islam like it does in Christianity?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28955/does-the-concept-of-grace-exist-in-islam-like-it-does-in-christianity)

Answer (score 1):

According to the definition included in your comment (quoted below) you can clearly see the similarities between the definiton and the verse I have queoted below:

> Grace means : grace has been defined, not as a created substance of
>   any kind, but as "the love and mercy given to us by God because God
>   desires us to have it, not because of anything we have done to earn
>   it"
>
> (6:54)Sahih International: And when those come to you who believe in
>   Our verses, say, "Peace be upon you. Your Lord has decreed upon
>   Himself mercy: that any of you who does wrong out of ignorance and
>   then repents after that and corrects himself - indeed, He is Forgiving
>   and Merciful."
>
> (30:21)Sahih International: And of His signs is that He created for you from
>   yourselves mates that you may find tranquillity in them; and He placed
>   between you affection and mercy. Indeed in that are signs for a people
>   who give thought.

Regarding your comment: "is the word love as a grace als used in koran?"

> “God does not forbid you from being good to those who have not fought
>   you in the religion or driven you from your homes, or from being just
>   towards them. God loves those who are just.” (Surat al-Mumtahana, 8)

If you do provide further definitons of the word "grace" then I will happily update my answer!

Although I don't like Wikipedia have a look at the divine names of god [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_God_in_Islam), one of these names is "Al Wadud" = The Loving

> The Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) told us:If Allah loves a
>   person, He calls Gabriel, saying, 'Allah loves so and so, O Gabriel
>   love him.'So Gabriel would love him and then would make an
>   announcement in the Heavens: 'Allah has loved so and-so therefore you
>   should love him also.'So all the dwellers of the Heavens would love
>   him, and then he is granted the pleasure of the people on the earth››
>   (Al-Bukhari, 7485).

May God Guide us all towards the righteous path!

Comment: Ok, but is the word love as a grace als used in koran?

Comment: @Marijn As stated in the comments there are various definitions of the word grace, Please list the definitions you are interested in, in your question this way every one can get a clearer Idea of what your after :) Also I updated my question!

Answer (score 0):

Ar-Rahman (most gracious) is a name of Allah and it appears in Chapter 1, Verse 2.

[Rahman] appears in the Quran 56 times, according to this Phonetic Word Search,
https://www.islamicity.org/ps/default.asp?UserString=Rahman&ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.islamicity.org%2FQuranSearch%2Fdefaultmobile.asp%3FAspxAutoDetectCookieSupport%3D1&ShowTranslation=on&ShowTransliteration=on&ShowArabic=on

The word [grace] also appears numerous times. It appears 313 times but many of these are related to his name [the dispenser of grace], according to a Word Search from above website.

Some examples of [grace] without attributed to His name,

■O children of Israel ! Remember those blessings of Mine with which I GRACEd you, and how I favoured you above all other people; - 2:47

■And you turned away after that-! And had it not been for God's favour upon you and His GRACE, you would surely have found yourselves among the lost; - 2:64

■It is they upon whom their Sustainer's blessings and GRACE are bestowed, and it is they, they who are on the right path! - 2:157

■O YOU who have attained to faith! Just retribution is ordained for you in cases of killing: the free for the free, and the slave for the slave, and the woman for the woman. [147] And if something [of his guilt] is remitted to a guilty person by his brother, [148] this [remission] shall be adhered to with fairness, and restitution to his fellow-man shall be made in a goodly manner. [149] This is an alleviation from your Sustainer, and an act of His GRACE. And for him who, none the less, [150] wilfully transgresses the bounds of what is right, there is grievous suffering in store: - 2:178

■And so, when you divorce women and they are about to reach the end of their waiting-term, then either retain them in a fair manner or let them go in a fair manner. But do not retain them against their will in order to hurt [them]: for he who does so sins indeed against himself. And do not take [these] messages of God in a frivolous spirit; and remember the blessings with which God has GRACEd you, and all the revelation and the wisdom which He has bestowed on you from on high in order to admonish you thereby; and remain conscious of God, and know that God has full knowledge of everything. - 2:231

■And forget not [that you are to act with] GRACE towards one another: verily, God sees all that you do. - 2:237

^^This is not a complete list; above verses are just from Chapter 2.